# Polarization of light upon reflection

Tags: visible-light, polarization

I was wondering (since I've looked pretty hard and haven't been able to find anything)- 
are there any models that explain the polarization of light upon reflection? Everywhere I've looked I've seen things like the Brewster angle mentioned, and empirical data, but I haven't yet found any theoretical models that explain this type of polarization. Can anybody point me in the right direction? Or have no such models been made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may wish to look at the [Fresnel formulas (see "Fresnel Equations" Wiki page)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations), which are derived from the Maxwell equations.

Comment: Well, when Fresnel first derived them, Maxwell wasn't even born.

Comment: @Ruslan: I wrote "are derived", not "were derived":-), as OP asked about "theoretical models".

Comment: Yeah, this was partly a joke. I was thinking that Fresnel must have had some phenomenological wave model to derive his equations from. If you know what it was, it'd be a useful addition to your answer.

Comment: @Ruslan Partly a joke but still a very interesting point historically - I'd never noticed this seemingly obvious point before as, like Akhmeteli, I learnt the Fresnel equations as being derived from ME (from Born and Wolf, in my case). A good question for Science and Math History SE, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks! And, I don't know if this merits another question or not on the site: qualitatively, how is this phenomenon explained?

Comment: @PhysicsLlama - see [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/233751/26969) for a qualitative explanation.