# How are electromagnetic waves actually produced?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

Can anyone explain me in baby steps how is an electromagnetic wave produced? I know this question is way too simple and, before you ban my question, I wanna add that I searched everywhere and I couldn't find an explanation on my understanding. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65339/how-and-why-do-accelerating-charges-radiate-electromagnetic-radiation) answer your question?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain why the explanations at the link are inadequate for you.

Comment: Related [How are the magnetic field lines in a electric dipole formed (step by step and graphically)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/355128/how-are-the-magnetic-field-lines-in-a-electric-dipole-formed-step-by-step-and-g/356045#356045)